# Authenticate users with multiple profiles using IdentityServer4

Tags: authentication, oauth-2.0, asp.net-core-2.0, identityserver4

How would you implement an authentication with **ASP.NET Core 2** and **IdentityServer4** that supports multiple profiles of users? The user structure looks like the following:

[image]

- Simple users are related to exactly one company. They don't have profiles.
- Profile users have multiple profiles. They are not related to one company, instead each of their profiles is related to one company.

The user has only one user name and one password. Users log in with these credentials and they can switch their profile during the session without having to re-enter their password. The important thing is that they don't have to choose the profile when logging in, all of them are available and the user can switch between them whenever he wants with one click. Basically, due to the legacy structure I'm working with I'll have to use the **ResourceOwnerPassword** flow. Shouldn't be a problem since all the involved parties are trusted.

I would assume that the final result should populate a **ClaimsPrincipal** with one **ClaimsIdentity** for simple users and multiple **ClaimsIdentities** for the profile users. However, I don't know how to set up this properly and also how to hook into IdentityServer's extension points properly.

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Personally i would simplify this. Don't link Users to companies, instead have all users link to at least one profile. You can setup profiles to be simple or complex as you wish. This way your Authentication is separate from Business Logic if that makes sense. That way you don't need to worry about authentication once the use signs in once, and they can change profiles within the business logic component as much as they want.